# How do I fix recurring email automation issue for Power Automate?

Tags: list, email, automation, workflow, power-automate

My company is using a workflow that sends out an email every few days if an intern has not completed an orientation quiz. The orientation workflow checks a Microsoft list that contains the intern names and orientation details. If the intern doesn't have an orientation start date for his entry in the list, then an email gets sent to him every few days. The problem is that even when interns complete the quiz it still gets sent out to the intern. I think the problem is that the workflow checks that the orientation start date is null and maybe that's what's causing the issue.
[image: workflow]

[image: condition]

JSON file for list:
{"statusCode":200,"headers":{"Transfer-Encoding":"chunked","Vary":"Origin,Accept-Encoding","X-NetworkStatistics":"1,4204800,0,16,64507,0,35062","X-SharePointHealthScore":"3","X-MS-SPConnector":"1","X-SP-SERVERSTATE":"ReadOnly=0","DATASERVICEVERSION":"3.0","SPClientServiceRequestDuration":"48","SPRequestDuration":"49","X-DataBoundary":"NONE","X-1DSCollectorUrl":"https://mobile.events.data.microsoft.com/OneCollector/1.0/","X-AriaCollectorURL":"https://browser.pipe.aria.microsoft.com/Collector/3.0/","SPRequestGuid":"ea07e98b-d1a0-480b-8c95-ffac44956acc","request-id":"ea07e98b-d1a0-480b-8c95-ffac44956acc","MS-CV":"i+kH6qDRC0iMlf+sRJVqzA.0","Strict-Transport-Security":"max-age=31536000","X-FRAME-OPTIONS":"SAMEORIGIN","Content-Security-Policy":"frame-ancestors 'self' teams.microsoft.com *.teams.microsoft.com *.skype.com *.teams.microsoft.us local.teams.office.com *.powerapps.com *.yammer.com *.officeapps.live.com *.office.com *.stream.azure-test.net *.microsoftstream.com *.dynamics.com *.microsoft.com onedrive.live.com *.onedrive.live.com securebroker.sharepointonline.com;","MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":"16.0.0.23717","X-Content-Type-Options":"nosniff","X-MS-InvokeApp":"1; RequireReadOnly","Timing-Allow-Origin":"*","x-ms-apihub-cached-response":"true","x-ms-apihub-obo":"false","Cache-Control":"max-age=0, private","Date":"Fri, 02 Jun 2023 05:02:47 GMT","P3P":"CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"","X-AspNet-Version":"4.0.30319","X-Powered-By":"ASP.NET","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Expires":"Thu, 18 May 2023 05:02:47 GMT","Last-Modified":"Fri, 02 Jun 2023 05:02:47 GMT","Content-Length":"2362"},"body":{"value":[{"@odata.etag":""1"","ItemInternalId":"1","ID":1,"Title":"Harry","LastName":"Potter","InternEmail":"real@email.com","Active":{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference","Id":1,"Value":"active"},"Active#Id":1,"SchoolEmail":" real@email.com","StartDate":"2023-06-01","OrientationEndDate":"2023-06-08","OData__x0034__x002e_5CheckStartDate":"2023-06-01","OrentationSentDate":"2023-05-25T07:00:00Z","OrientationStartDate":"2023-06-01T07:00:00Z","OrientationCheckin":"2023-05-25","OrientationCheck":"Yes","OData__x0034__x002e_5QuizReadytobeSent":"No","RTG":{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference","Id":0,"Value":"R"},"RTG#Id":0,"Created":"2023-06-02T01:22:55Z","Author":{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser","Claims":"i:0#.f|membership|fake@fake.com","DisplayName":"person","Email":" fake@fake.com ","Picture":"https://greentreechina.sharepoint.com/sites/GreentreeHR/*layouts/15/UserPhoto.aspx?Size=L&AccountName=fake@fake.com","Department":null,"JobTitle":null},"Author#Claims":"i:0#.f|membership| fake@fake.com ","DeleteIntern_x003f*":false,"Modified":"2023-06-02T01:22:55Z","Editor":{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser","Claims":"i:0#.f|membership|andrewisaacrosenthal@greentree.group","DisplayName":"Andrew Isaac Rosenthal","Email":" fake@fake.com ","Picture":"https://greentreechina.sharepoint.com/sites/GreentreeHR/*layouts/15/UserPhoto.aspx?Size=L&AccountName= fake@fake.com ","Department":null,"JobTitle":null},"Editor#Claims":"i:0#.f|membership|fake@fake.com","TeamEmail":" fake@fake.com ","SGReminderTimes":0.0,"{Identifier}":"Lists%252fMyTest%252f1*.000","{IsFolder}":false,"{Thumbnail}":{"Large":null,"Medium":null,"Small":null},"{Link}":"https://greentreechina.sharepoint.com/sites/GreentreeHR/*layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId=82119073%2D3cdb%2D49d2%2Dace1%2D7065d2009a53&ID=1&ContentTypeID=0x0100F358CD037A56064EB15A0470DF8C2D5C","{Name}":"Harry","{FilenameWithExtension}":"Harry","{Path}":"Lists/MyTest/","{FullPath}":"Lists/MyTest/1*.000","{HasAttachments}":false,"{VersionNumber}":"1.0"}]}}

I think the issue might be how the workflow checks the orientation sent date or start date. The orientation sent date starts a week before the quiz gets sent out and so we check if it's not null. The orientation start date is supposed to be empty until the quiz gets finished, hence why we check if it's null. Maybe a better way could be done. The orientation start and sent dates are columns in a Microsoft List.

Comment: You'd need to show us an example of the JSON from the SharePoint list item that you're running the condition over.  Too hard to help without it.

Comment: @Skin As you can see from the picture I posted, my entry has Orientation Start Date filled out, so it shouldn't trigger the mailing event. The condition evaluates to false, which means that the mailing event shouldn't be triggered. I don't understand why the mailing is happening when it's not triggered.

Comment: Can you please post it as text?  I can't recreate anything if need be with the image.